# Generate a random interval where probability of n appearing is 1/n

Tags: algorithm, probability

Let's say we have a news website with 100 pages each displaying several articles, and we want to parse regularly the website to keep statistics on the number of commentaries per article.
The number of commentaries on a article will change rapidly on new articles (so on the first pages), and really slowly on the very old article (on the last pages).
So I will want to parse the first pages way more often than the last pages.

A solution to this problem I imagined would be each time to generate an interval of the pages we want to parse, with the additional requirement that n in this interval would have a probability 1/n of appearing.
For example, we would parse the page 1 every time.
The page 2 would appear in the interval half of the time.
The page 3, 1/3 of the time...

Our algorithm would then generate the 'interval' [1,1] most of the time. The interval [1,2] would be less likely, [1,3] even less ... and [1,100] would be really rare.

Do you see a way to implement this algorithm with the usual random function of most of the languages ?
Is there another way to solve the problem (parse more often the recent content on a website) making more sense ?

Thanks for your help.

**edit:**
Here is an implementation in Python based on the answer provided by @david-eisenstat.
I tried to implement the version with random() generating integers, but I obtain strange results.

```
# return a number between 1 and n
def randPage(n):
    while True:
        r = floor(1 / (1 - random()))   
        if r <= n:
            return r
```

Comment: Would this just be the interval [1, rand(n)] ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution

Comment: [1, rand(n)] would mean that any interval has an equal probability of appearing 1/n time.  
Here I want for example the interval [1,2] to be way more likely to appear than the interval [1,100]

Comment: Changing to the Geometric distribution as suggested above sounds good: you will see at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number that the so-called probabilities you seem to be asking for sum to a number that quickly exceeds 1 and in fact continues increasing without limit. To generate arbitrary rough discrete distributions, you might consider http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a function `random()` that returns doubles in the interval `[0, 1)`, then you look at pages `1` to `floor(1 / (1 - random()))`. Page `n` is examined if and only if the output of `random()` is in the interval `[1 - 1/n, 1)`, which has length `1/n`.

If you're using an integer `random()` function in the interval `[0, RAND_MAX]`, then let `k = random()` and look at `RAND_MAX / k` pages if `k != 0` or all of them if `k == 0`.

Comment: Thanks it seems to be the solution.  
I am doing some test, and sometime the algorithm return big numbers (ex: 1063), what should I do with these results if I want to stay in a range (ex: < 100) and not change the probabilities ?  
Should I discard them ? Or use a modulo on my range ?  
Doing something like: `if r > 100 then r = 100` would obviously change the probabilities.

Comment: @BIBIwood It doesn't change the probability of an individual page being visited.

Comment: One that exists, anyway.